# RTL "Received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement. Received has value: null" due to having to use ReactDOM.render() in test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm pretty confident this is due to the RTL `render` not being used, but I'm not sure where the `render` should go given I apparently have to use `ReactDOM.react`. At least it was needed to resolve one 4-5 errors I got along the way.

App and test code...

```
// App.jsx

import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import Authentication from './Authentication';

import configureStore, { history } from '../services/history';

const App = () => {
  const protectedRoute = compose(Timers, RequireAuth);

  const store = configureStore();

  return (
    <div data-testid='App'>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Authentication} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
// Authentication.jsx

import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Authentication extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <div data-testid='Authentication' id='auth'>
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Started out with this test:

```
// Authentication.test.jsx

import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import Authentication from './Authentication';


test('authentication page renders', () => {
  render(<Authentication />);
  const auth = screen.getByTestId('Authentication');
  expect(auth).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Which resulted in:

```
Error: Uncaught [Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Form(Connect(Signin)))". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(Form(Connect(Signin))) in connect options.]
```

Addressing this issue, and 4-5 other subsequent errors, has resulted in the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import Authentication from './Authentication';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);
const store = mockStore({
  auth: {
    authenticated: true,
  },
});

test('authentication page renders', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Authentication />
      </MemoryRouter>
    </Provider>,
    div
  );
  const authentication = screen.queryByTestId('Authentication');
  expect(authentication).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Which results in:

```
received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement.
    Received has value: null

      28 |   );
      29 |   const authentication = screen.queryByTestId('Authentication');
    > 30 |   expect(authentication).toBeInTheDocument();
         |                          ^
      31 | });
      32 |
```

Again, pretty sure this is from not using RTLs `render`. Not sure where it should go and adding it creates the first error I had so I'm going in circles.

Any suggestions?

If it is helpful I could retrace all my previous steps and post the various error messages which led me to this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, somewhere along the line of addressing the various error messages that came up, one fix was adding `ReactDOM.render()`... thought it was necessary, turns out it was not.

This is sufficient and works:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

import Authentication from './Authentication';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);
const store = mockStore({
  auth: {
    authenticated: true,
  },
});

test('authentication page renders', () => {
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Authentication />
      </MemoryRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
  const authentication = screen.getByTestId('Authentication');
  expect(authentication).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```